# Point Spending Tool - Difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jsfiddle

I've made this small tool but I'm not sure how to achieve what I need.

- I would like it to subtract from the **"Points Left"** when adding to the others.
  (Not going below zero into the negative, only 30 points).
- I would also like to prevent going BELOW the initial numbers in **"Weapon Power"** and **"Magic Power"**.
  (I would like to be able to only spend a maximum of 25 points into one "power")

I think it kind of explains itself so maybe I'm just confusing you more.

Any ideas?

- **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/48/edit)**

Comment: What does this question have to do with google? In fact, what _does_ this question have to do with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your number input elements distinct ids, because when you do `document.getElementById`, it will only return you the first element with the given ids.

Then, you need to give another distinct ID to the "points left" field for each character, and update that one. To do that, you'll need to pass to add and substract the correct value ( `add(warrior, 'weapon'), add(wizard, 'magic')`).

You need to be able to get your IDs from your warrior or wizard object, so you could try doing this:

```
var wizard = {
    weapon:"idOfWeaponField", magic:"idOfMagicField", points:"idOfPointsField"
};
```

where the string values are the ids of your elements.
Then, within your add function, you can access your id like this

```
function add(character, statName){
    var myID = character[statName];
}
```

and update the correct input value.

EDIT: code [here](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/53/edit?html,js,output).

> I would also like to prevent going BELOW the initial numbers in "Weapon Power" and "Magic Power". >(I would like to be able to only spend a maximum of 25 points into one "power")

Basically, you've seen what I did with the points left, when I said `if(pointsVal.value == 0) return;` ? You should be able to implement any constraint you like using that. 
I modified mine to give an example where the limits are at their initial values.

If you only want to spend a given number of points on one of the powers, you'll have to substract the limit from the current number and return from add() without changing the value if the number exceeds the threshold. That should be pretty easy with what you have now, since you don't have to change the character object to do it.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post to add it.